# Huawei e1550 modem not detecting ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, usb, usb-modem, 3g

I have done lots of research to connect my old huawei e1550 modem with ubuntu 14.04 os, I have found couple of possible solution but none is working. So, here is what I get when I connect my modem in usb port by `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 12d1:1446 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband 
stick (modem on)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:643e Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21bc Broadcom Corp. BCM2070 Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and this is `dmesg` log:

```
[ 6075.782165] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[ 6075.885637] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1446
[ 6075.885648] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 6075.885653] usb 2-1.2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[ 6075.885657] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technology
[ 6075.891403] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6075.891872] scsi host20: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 6075.892263] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6075.892476] scsi host21: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.1
[ 6077.519920] init: usb-modeswitch-upstart main process (6139) killed by ABRT signal
[ 6078.901780] scsi 20:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 6078.905564] scsi 21:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 6078.912631] sr 20:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[ 6078.913196] sr 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 6078.913481] sr 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[ 6078.914554] sd 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 6078.924676] sd 21:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I have tried by `sudo modprobe option` , `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x12d1 -p 1446 -R -W` , I have created udev rules like this ->

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1446", RUN+="/lib/udev/usb_modeswitch --vendor 0x12d1 --product 0x1446 --type option-zerocd"
```

But nothing working. Modem isn't showing up. Please help me.